# 8 seater, 4wd, towing capacity 10000 pounds does it exist in the USA or can anything me modified to meet that?

Tags: chevrolet, towing, 4wd

The CHEVY express 3500/GMC Savana is close but it's only 2WD.  Can it be modified to have 4wd?  There are other 4wd vans, but towing capacity is unclear/poor.

Comment: Please be more specific, and use units - 10,000 what? It also helps if you say where you are, as different vehicles are available in different countries with different specifications,  in my country you'd need an HGV to tow more than 3500kg.

Answer (score 0):

A Ford E450 chassis has a towing capacity of at least 10,000 lbs and up to the weight of the finished E450 vehicle, maximum 22,000 lbs.

[Here is a story in Motor Trend](https://www.motortrend.com/features/4x4-school-bus-ford-e-450/) of a person who converted an E450 school bus to 4WD. If you follow the slide show in the story, you'll see technical details about the 4x4 conversion.

[image: e]